# Main list and child list in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I just started vue.js and I try to create a todo like application. The only difference is that for each element of the list, I have a child list. The main list works fine but the child list does not work. I try several hours to find what is wrong with my code but I can not solve the problem. Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    groups: []
  },
  methods: {
    deleteGroup(group) {
      const groupIndex = this.groups.indexOf(group);
      this.groups.splice(groupIndex, 1);
    },
    createGroup() {
      this.groups.push({
        title: "",
        listMode: 0,
        properties: []
      });
    },
    deleteProperty(group, property) {
      const propertyIndex = properties.indexOf(group.properties, property);
      group.properties.splice(propertyIndex, 1);
    },
    createProperty(group) {
      group.properties.push({
        name: "",
        type: 0
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" style="margin: auto; width: 600px;">
    <div
      v-for="(group, index) in groups"
      style=" border: 2px solid gray; margin-bottom: 20px;"
    >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Group Name :</label>
        <input class="form-control" v-model="group.title" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">List Mode :</label>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="group.listMode">
          <option value="0">Fields</option>
          <option value="1">List of Fields</option>
        </select>
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
        <div
          v-for="(property, Index2) in group.properties"
          style=" border: 2px solid gray; margin-bottom: 20px;"
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Property Name :</label>
            <input class="form-control" v-model="property.name" />
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Type :</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="peroprty.type">
              <option value="0">Fields</option>
              <option value="1">List of Fields</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
          <!--
            <button class='btn btn-success' v-on:click="deleteProperty(group, property)"><i class='trash icon'></i> Delete</button>
          -->
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="createProperty(group)">
          Create Group
        </button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="deleteGroup(group)">
        <i class="trash icon"></i> Delete
      </button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="createGroup()">
      Create Group
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what "does not work" means?  Error messages? Unexpected output?  No output? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your v-model currently with name: "peroprty"

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="peroprty.type">
```

Try update to "property"

Obs: You always can look on console/debug of chrome to see what kind error can be. 
Especially when trying to do some event with: v-for, v-if, @click, and among others attrs of vue